# App crashed after typing wrong password

Tags: android, exception, authentication

my app crashed always if i put a wrong password in my Loginscreen and i dont know how i can handle this exception. Below my code.

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private EditText eUsername, ePasswort;
    private Button bAnmelden, bRegestrieren;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    //Encoder
   JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "Du bist jetzt eingeloggt";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME_PREF = "BENUTZERNAME";


    // Verbindung zum Server
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.77.1:80/webservice/login.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_);

        // Editfelder
        eUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.FELD_username);
        ePasswort = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.FELD_passwort);

        //Button
        bAnmelden = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BUTTON_anmelden);
        bRegestrieren= (Button)findViewById(R.id.BUTTON_regestrieren);

        //Hier werden die Button mit einen Klicklistener ausgestattet
        bAnmelden.setOnClickListener(this);
        bRegestrieren.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.BUTTON_anmelden:

                new VersuchLogin().execute();

            break;

            case R.id.BUTTON_regestrieren:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    //
    class VersuchLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

       // Hier wird schon ausgeführt
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Versucht einzuloggen...");
            //unbestimmt
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Checkt erfogreichen Tag
            int erfolgreich;
            String username = eUsername.getText().toString();
            String passwort = ePasswort.getText().toString();

            try{
             // Hier werden die Parameter gebildet
                List<NameValuePair> parameter = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
                parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwort));

                //Holt sich die Daten beim anfragen des HTTP
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL,"POST",parameter);


                //Json erfolgreich entcondiert
                erfolgreich = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if ( erfolgreich ==1){

                    //Teile die Userdaten
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString(TAG_USERNAME_PREF,eUsername.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit();


                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);

                    return (TAG_MESSAGE);

                } else {
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //bendet den Dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if(file_url != null);
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: You start activity in doInBackground method and then call pDialog.dismiss(); ?? Logically crashes, how do you dispose of the dialog without have a view?? post the logcat for more advice.

Comment: you have an unwanted semi-colon at this line - if(file_url != null); and also move dismiss below toast.maketext

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is parsing the Error message, I think. Error message is not a valid Json String or not a Json string.

You can check the response message from web service. 
If there is no error, parse your json string.
Else, Show Toast message using the error message you get.

That is only one of many solutions. You can do many things. Also you can use the Error Codes from response.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got null response in login? Do you check it what response is come when password is wrong?

Additionally you should put if condition like this

```
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL,"POST",parameter);
        if(json!=null){
           //Json erfolgreich entcondiert
           erfolgreich = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
         }
```